# Ruby Rails precompiling assets vs. using the asset pipeline

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, plugins, asset-pipeline, precompile

I'm wondering when to use `Rails.application.config.assets.precompile` to include Javascript plugins, and when to use the asset pipeline.  From what I understand, the asset pipeline minifies all files listed in it, and it makes this minified file available to the entire application. However, you can use `Rails.application.config.assets.precompile` in **config/initializers/assets.rb** to allow a plugin to be used only on specific pages.  Is this understanding correct?

For instance, if I have the lines below in my **config/initializers/assets.rb** file:

```
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( plugins/footable/angular-footable.js )
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( plugins/footable/footable.all.min.js )
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( plugins/footable/footable.core.css )
```

Then I can use the Foo Table plugin in my **app/views/users/index.html.erb** file:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'plugins/footable/angular-footable' %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'plugins/footable/footable.all.min' %>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'plugins/footable/footable.core' %>
```

Is this a proper usage?

The reason I ask is because I want to use the Foo Table plugin (among others) only on the **app/views/users/index.html.erb** page.  I thought about including the plugin in the asset pipeline, but I didn't want to bog down the rest of my application with Javascript code that was only needed by one page.

Answer (score 4):

I found an answer to my own question on this website: https://launchschool.com/blog/rails-asset-pipeline-best-practices.  Basically, the answer, is yes, my understanding is correct.

Here are the relevant pieces of the article:
[image]

[image]